# how to make timer using system.threading namespace and execute function automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have one function to execute some task.but I don't know how to make that function to execute using the system.threading namespace.I tried the system.timers namespace to execute that function but it slows down my site.so please help me to make it using threading namespace.Any help greatly appreciated.

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Timer timer = new Timer(120000.00);

        timer.Enabled = true;


        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

        timer.Start();
    }
     protected static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        Synch _synch = new Synch();
        _synch.autosynch();
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code you have, people can help then.

Comment: You should use cron job. Look at quartz.NET

Comment: Using any form of `Timer` is wrong-headed. Scott Hanselman wrote a good post summarizing [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Comment: And *one* reason why your current attempt fails is discussed in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx): "a Timer is subject to garbage collection when there are no references to it. The fact that a Timer is still active does not prevent it from being collected."

Comment: Do not use timers inside ASP.NET

Comment: Why should I not use timer in asp. Net?

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of System.Timer for performing any task on periodically on specific time

```
private System.Threading.Timer timer;
private void SetUpTimer()
{

     this.timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x =>
     {
         this.OnTimeEvent();
     } , null, 0, "Interval to run your thread.");
}

private void OnTimeEvent()
{
   // Do your other thing Here
}
```